Pass previous version of document from pre to post hook in Mongoose
In my mongoose 8.1.3 setup, I have a post findOneAndUpdate hook where I need to compare the previous version of the document to the latest and based on changes run some functions.
My current solution involves setting a global variable and passing that between hooks, but I worry with Javascript threading that this might cause a mismatch between concurrent document saves.
This is the general idea:
let previous = {};

x.pre('findOneAndUpdate',async function (next) {
  try {
     previous  = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery()).select({logs: 0, updatedAt: 0, _id:0}).lean().exec();
     :
     next();
  } catch (e) {
     new Error ('error')
  }
}

x.post('findOneAndUpdate',async function (document) {
  try {
     const current = document.toObject()
     const added = addedDiff(previous, current); // Some function to see what was added
     :
  } catch (e) {
     new Error ('error')
  }
}

Is there a more reliable or better way to achieve this ?
